# How to get preloaded module name in C++

Tags: c++, module, lua

I wonder if it's possible to create a C++ function that returns(or prints) the preloaded module name of the current script.

For example, I would like to create `getModuleName()` function in the following code so running the code can print `A` as a result.

```
#include "lua.hpp"

void main()
{
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    lua_settop(L, 0);
    luaL_dostring(L, "package.preload['A'] = function ()\n"
                     "local a = {}\n"
                     "a.name = my.getModuleName()\n"
                     "print(a.name)\n"
                     "return a end");
    luaL_dostring(L, "require 'A'\n");
    lua_close(L);
}
```

How can I create a `getModuleName()` function in C++?

If it's not possible with C++, I would like to know if it's possible to do it in Lua.

P.S: I'm using SWIG for binding C++ code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require` calls the preload function with the name it was given as the first argument.

```
#include "lua.hpp"

int main() {
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    lua_settop(L, 0);
    luaL_dostring(L, "package.preload['A'] = function(this)\n"
                     "local a = {}\n"
                     "a.name = this\n"
                     "print(a.name)\n"
                     "return a end");
    luaL_dostring(L, "require 'A'\n");
    lua_close(L);
}
```

```
$ clang++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -I /usr/include/lua5.2 test.cpp -llua5.2
$ ./a.out 
A
```

#### Avoiding to pass and argument

I don't see why you would want to do this but it is easily doable by overriding the `require` function with your own version.  For simplicity I only show the Lua code:

```
local require_original = require
function require(name, ...)
    current_module = name
    local val = table.pack(require_original(name, ...))
    current_module = nil
    return table.unpack(val,1,val.n)
end

package.preload["test"] = function()
    print("While loading:", current_module)
    return {}
end

print("Before loading:", current_module)
require("test")
print("After loading:", current_module)
```

```
$ lua5.2 test.lua
Before loading: nil
While loading:  test
After loading:  nil
```

---

#### Answer to the misunderstood question

`package.preload` is just a regular Lua table which you can traverse just as any other Lua table from the C-API.  In this case you will have to traverse it twice, once to determine which preloads are already there before adding a new one, and then again after you added your preload.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>

#include "lua.hpp"

int main() {
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    lua_settop(L, 0);

    // Determine all existing preloads
    std::unordered_set<std::string> known_preloads;
    lua_getglobal(L, "package");
    lua_getfield(L, -1, "preload");
    lua_pushnil(L);
    while (lua_next(L, -2) != 0) {
        known_preloads.emplace(lua_tostring(L, -2)); // pops key
        lua_pop(L, 1); // pops value
    }
    lua_pop(L, 2); // pop preload and package

    // Add a new preload
    luaL_dostring(L, "package.preload['A'] = function ()\n"
                     "local a = {}\n"
                     "a.name = my.getModuleName()\n"
                     "print(a.name)\n"
                     "return a end");
    luaL_dostring(L, "require 'A'\n");

    // Determine which preloads are new
    std::unordered_set<std::string> new_preloads;
    lua_getglobal(L, "package");
    lua_getfield(L, -1, "preload");
    lua_pushnil(L);
    while (lua_next(L, -2) != 0) {
        std::string current = lua_tostring(L, -2); // pops key
        if (known_preloads.find(current) == known_preloads.end()) {
            new_preloads.emplace(current);
        }
        lua_pop(L, 1); // pops value
    }
    lua_pop(L, 2); // pop preload and package

    // Print the new preloads
    for (auto const & preload : new_preloads) {
        std::cout << preload << '\n';
    }

    lua_close(L);
}
```

---

You might want to consider using [Sol2](https://sol2.readthedocs.io/).  It's the fastest wrapper around the Lua C-API for C++ that exists.  It requires C++14 and it's totally worth it.  See how I didn't worry about the stack a single time!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>

#define SOL_CHECK_ARGUMENTS 1
#include "sol.hpp"

int main() {
    sol::state L;
    L.open_libraries();

    // Determine all existing preloads
    std::unordered_set<std::string> known_preloads;
    L.get<sol::table>("package").get<sol::table>("preload").for_each(
        [&](sol::object &key, sol::object &) {
            known_preloads.emplace(key.as<std::string>());
        });

    // Add a new preload
    L.script("package.preload['A'] = function ()\n"
             "local a = {}\n"
             "a.name = my.getModuleName()\n"
             "print(a.name)\n"
             "return a end");
    L.script("require 'A'\n");

    // Determine which preloads are new
    std::unordered_set<std::string> new_preloads;
    L.get<sol::table>("package").get<sol::table>("preload").for_each(
        [&](sol::object &key_, sol::object &) {
            std::string key = key_.as<std::string>();
            if (known_preloads.find(key) == known_preloads.end()) {
                new_preloads.emplace(key);
            }
        });

    // Print the new preloads
    for (auto const & preload : new_preloads) {
        std::cout << preload << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your example prints all existing preloads but is it not possible to get the name of the current preload name in the middle of Lua script? In other words, Would it be not possible to create something like `my.getModuleName()` that works accurately?

Comment: Wow, using the updated solution works like magic. But wouldn't it be possible to create a C++ function that returns string `A` without using `this` as an argument? (e.g. `a.name = my.getName()`)

Comment: @ZackLee Maybe you are able to punch the stack using the debug library until it gives you that info but that will most likely be a very complicated solution.  What's wrong with just taking the argument?

Comment: I see. Thank you for your answer. The preload name will also be used as a key for lightuserdata and I wanted to be able to automatically access the userdata from a wrapped C++ Class without having to pass preload name as a class constructor. I think I need to at least do `MyClass(this)` to create a class based on your answer which is simpler than typing the full key name.

Comment: @ZackLee This sounds like extremely horrible design.  It's always a bad sign if things rely on what they are named.

Comment: I'm also considering to create a `static vector<data *> datas` and then `push_back()`/`pop_back()` the pointer to a `data` whenever I run a Lua script so wrapped classes/functions can access the `data *` using `datas.back()` . This way, I don't even need to use `lightuserdata` or pass `this` as argument. I hope it's not a horrible design.

Comment: @ZackLee Regarding the access of unnamed argument I asked a new question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51515701).  I don't know anything about the internal of your program but are sure the storage duration of `datas` should be `static`?

Comment: Thank you asking the question. Yes, I believe it should be `static` since many instance of classes should share it. Also, it's easier to make it accessible from `MyBindings.h` file.

Comment: @ZackLee I realised that there is a relatively simple method to access the name of the module without passing an argument but it involves overriding the `require` function.  See updated answer for details.

Comment: @Henri_Menke Thank you for your updated answer. I tried it but overriding the `require` function causes crash when calling `lua_getfield`. Please have a look at this question Sir: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520697/crashes-when-calling-lua-getfield-after-overriding-the-require

Comment: @ZackLee I forgot to return the module from the overridden `require` function.  My updated answer should solve the problem.

Comment: @Henri_Menke Thank you so much for your answer. I will give you a bounty tomorrow.