# How to access discarded function arguments?

Tags: lua

In Lua, calling a function with excess arguments will simply discard those.  Is there a possibility with the `debug` library to access these discarded arguments? (I'm not looking for variadic functions)

```
function test()
    local info = debug.getinfo(1, "u")
    print(info.nparams) -- just 0 :(
    -- how to access the discarded arguments?
end

test(42, "Hello World!", 3.14)
```

---

Edit: As Luiz-Henrique informed me in the comments, this is not possible in standard Lua.  He also asked for more context, so I'm going to repeat the problem that I was trying to solve to answer another question.  In this other question the OP wanted to access the name that module has inside `package.preload` from within the loader function but without taking it as an argument as it is passed by `require`.  I don't know why but this led me to the question whether it is possible to access discarded arguments.

```
package.preload["test"] = function()
    local info = debug.getinfo(1, "u")
    print(info.nparams) -- just 0 :(
    -- how to access the name without taking it as an argument
    return {}
end

require("test")
```

Comment: There is no way. What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: @lhf Not my problem.  I was answering another question and this came up and I didn't know whether it was possible, so I posted a question myself.  I'm not super keen on doing this and if you post “No“ as an answer I will accept that.

Comment: `...`, but the function needs to be marked with `...` as well. Unfortunately using `...` in a non-vararg function is an error.

Comment: @lhf I added some more context to what led me to this question.

Comment: Could you replace `package.preload["test"]` with your own vararg function which would call the original function?